# NSURLSession return data

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have a problem. I want to download an image from the Internet, and display an "indicator" while downloading. The problem is when there is no internet connection, the method "**downloadedFrom**" enters within "**if error!= nil**" and for that reason the "indicator" never break. This is my code.

```
var imageArray:[String]! = ["http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a01.png", "http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a02.png", "http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a03.png", "http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a04.png", "http://findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a05.png"]   

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let newCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as! UserCell_TableViewCell
        let selectedUser = userArray[indexPath.row]

        newCell.userDescription?.text = selectedUser.getFirstName() + " " + selectedUser.getLastName()
            let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(4)
            let arrayIndex = Int(randomNumber)
            let urlImage = imageArray[arrayIndex]

            newCell.loadIndicator.startAnimating()

            downloadedFrom(urlImage) { userImage in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    newCell.userImage.image = userImage
                    newCell.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()
                }

                self.userArray[indexPath.row].setImage(userImage)
            }

        return newCell
    }

    func downloadedFrom(urlLink :String, completionHandler: (UIImage) -> ())
    {
        if let urlData = NSURL(string: urlLink) {
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlData) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                } else {
                    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                        let userImage = httpResponse.statusCode == 200 ? UIImage(data: data!) : UIImage(named: "unknownImage")

                        completionHandler(userImage!)
                    }}
                }.resume()
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
    import UIKit

    class UserCell_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var loadIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func downloadedFrom(urlLink :String)
    {

        self.loadIndicator.startAnimating()

        if let urlData = NSURL(string: urlLink) {

            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlData) { (data, response, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    print("error = \(error)")

                    self.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    return

                } else {

                    // El servidor contesta la petición, pero la imágen puede no existir.
                    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

                        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                                self.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                                self.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()

                            }}
                    }}

                }.resume()
        }

    }

}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let newCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as! UserCell_TableViewCell
        let selectedUser = userArray[indexPath.row]

        newCell.userDescription?.text = selectedUser.getFirstName() + " " + selectedUser.getLastName()

            let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(4)

            let arrayIndex = Int(randomNumber)

            let urlImage = imageArray[arrayIndex]

            newCell.downloadedFrom(urlImage)

        return newCell
    }
```

The problem that brings me to do this, is that I need you download the image to save it to an array, the array completeness within the method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

First I want to mention that it is bad practice to try to dispatch a loading loop (even in a separate thread) inside the table cell method. The block you are executing will capture the `newCell` pointer, so if the image is loaded after the cell is moved off the table and became reused, the image will be loaded into the wrong table cell.

The best way to solve the problem is to move the loading function into the cell's class itself. So when configuring the cell, just provide the link to the cell, and let the cell handle the image loading.

To address the initial concern, you can modify the loading process such that if the cell is moved off the table, (aka if `prepareForReuse()` is called), cancel the loading process.

In the cell's class, you can add a check for internet connection such that when an error is returned, stop the indicator. This becomes a lot clearer to implement when you move the functionality to the cell's class.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new in swift. You can help me a little more? I edit the post to see if I understood what he said.

Comment: That looks mostly right! You just need to address the concern of what happens when the cell is moved off the screen. So when that happens, the cell is marked for reuse, so you want to stop loading the image (unless you don't reuse cells). This can be achieved by adding a `BOOL` flag, and set it to false when the cell should not load the image (in `prepareForReuse()`). When the image is loaded in your downloadedFrom(), you want to check this flag to see whether you really should load the image.